# Overriding Persist() in Custom BLC

Tags: acumatica

I've found information on how to override the Persist() function for a customization extension for an out-of-the-box BLC, but I cannot find anything regarding a custom built BLC. I need to insert an item into the cache right before RowPersisting() begins, but using public void Persist(PersistDelegate baseMethod) is not working since I do not have a PersistDelegate object defined. The error I receive is:

> PX.Data.PXException: An invalid type has been specified for the data source.

Is there a way to override Persist() in a custom BLC? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding the Persist method in a custom BLC is not different then overriding any virtual method in C#:

```
public class ARSalesPriceMaint : PXGraph<ARSalesPriceMaint>
{
    ...
    public override void Persist()
    {
        foreach (ARSalesPrice price in Records.Cache.Inserted)
        {
            ARSalesPrice lastPrice = FindLastPrice(this, price);
            if (lastPrice?.EffectiveDate > price.EffectiveDate && price.ExpirationDate == null)
            {
                Records.Cache.RaiseExceptionHandling<ARSalesPrice.expirationDate>(price, price.ExpirationDate, new PXSetPropertyException(ErrorMessages.FieldIsEmpty, PXUIFieldAttribute.GetDisplayName<ARSalesPrice.expirationDate>(Records.Cache)));
                throw new PXSetPropertyException(ErrorMessages.FieldIsEmpty, PXUIFieldAttribute.GetDisplayName<ARSalesPrice.expirationDate>(Records.Cache));
            }
            ValidateDuplicate(this, Records.Cache, price);
        }
        foreach (ARSalesPrice price in Records.Cache.Updated)
        {
            ARSalesPrice lastPrice = FindLastPrice(this, price);
            if (lastPrice?.EffectiveDate > price.EffectiveDate && price.ExpirationDate == null)
            {
                Records.Cache.RaiseExceptionHandling<ARSalesPrice.expirationDate>(price, price.ExpirationDate, new PXSetPropertyException(ErrorMessages.FieldIsEmpty, PXUIFieldAttribute.GetDisplayName<ARSalesPrice.expirationDate>(Records.Cache)));
                throw new PXSetPropertyException(ErrorMessages.FieldIsEmpty, PXUIFieldAttribute.GetDisplayName<ARSalesPrice.expirationDate>(Records.Cache));
            }
            ValidateDuplicate(this, Records.Cache, price);
        }
        base.Persist();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do I just need to make the .Persist(); function call at the end of my logic for it to continue its normal saving process? The reason I brought this up is because I did do the override void Persist(), but it didn't perform the actual save anymore.

Comment: Correct, you should invoke `base.Persist();` after your logic to kick in the actual save process.